# (ffmpeg) VBV buffer size not set - MPG to MPG

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg

I have a MPG file (mpeg2) with two audio streams.

I just want to remove one of the audio stream without re-encode or quality loss.

Here's my command (I don't -map the audio I want to delete) :

```
ffmpeg -i input.MPG
-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1
-vcodec mpeg2video
-c:a mp2
-y
output.MPG
```

It works BUT I have this error / warning :

```
[mpeg @ 0000020268f9a300] VBV buffer size not set, using default size of 230KB
If you want the mpeg file to be compliant to some specification
Like DVD, VCD or others, make sure you set the correct buffer size
```

And of course, the quality of the output video is just terrible !

How can I fix this ?

Thanks a lot for your answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove one stream in your media, **copy everything** BUT the stream you want to remove.

### Finding all streams inside media

You get all the streams inside your media with this:

```
ffprobe mediafile.mpg 2>&1 | grep -i stream
```

#### Example

This is an example output of one of my media:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 171 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 55 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Stream #0:3(deu): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
Stream #0:4(fra): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129 kb/s
```

It has two video streams (from two cameras) and three audio streams (in different languages).

### How to copy (lossless)

Now, if you want to **copy** a stream, you need the word `copy` as a *codec*. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i media.mpg -c copy output.mkv
```

or more explicit (video and audio codec)

```
ffmpeg -i media.mpg -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mkv
```

As a standard this will copy only **the first** video stream, the first audio stream, the first subtitle stream etc.

To copy all streams :

```
ffmpeg -i media.mpg -map 0 -c copy output.mkv
```

Note: `mkv` is a modern media container (`avi` and `mpg` are quite old and outdated, `mp4` is also newer, but `mkv` is more flexible). But you can also use `mpg` container as output.

### Remove stream

Now I will show you how to select the streams to copy with my example media file from above. The other streams will be omitted (= removed):

```
ffmpeg -i media.mkv -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 output.mkv
```

As you have seen above, I had two video streams (0:0 and 0:1), and three audio streams (0:2, 0:3, 0:4). In my command I have omitted stream 0:1 and 0:4 (I removed them).

### Your case

For your case you should have 0:0 (video) and 0:1 (audio) and 0:2 (audio):

```
ffmpeg input.mpg -c copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 output.mpg
```